# How to update a looped html tablesorter table self-updating table

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

Total newbie here. The following situation has been bugging me for days and days of work now.

I created a dashboard with python and flask. For presentation purposes I want to use tablesorter to display the current status of the system and update the tables every second or so.

Now, for normal html tables everything works as intended with the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="table" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Total memory</th>
            <th>Used memory</th>
            <th>Free memory</th>
            <th>Available memory w/o swapping</th>
            <th>Percent used</th>
            <th>Percent free</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="memSizeGbUpdate">{{memConst["sizeGb"]}} GB</span></td>
            <td><span id="memUsedGbUpdate">{{mem["usedGb"]}} GB</span></td>
            <td><span id="memFreeGbUpdate">{{mem["freeGb"]}} GB</span></td>
            <td><span id="memAvailGbUpdate">{{mem["availGb"]}} GB</span></td>
            <td><span id="memPercUsedUpdate">{{mem["percUsed"]}} %</span></td>
            <td><span id="memPercFreeUpdate">{{mem["percFree"]}} %</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#memSizeGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memSizeGbUpdate");
        $("#memUsedGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memUsedGbUpdate");
        $("#memFreeGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memFreeGbUpdate");
        $("#memAvailGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memAvailGbUpdate");
        $("#memPercUsedUpdate").load("./memory.html #memPercUsedUpdate");
        $("#memPercFreeUpdate").load("./memory.html #memPercFreeUpdate");
    },1000);
});
```

The table updates each variable after 1 second - great!

But how do I get the same result with a "for" loop on the html side. For example I want the page to display the cpu usage for all available cores. I have a python list of dictionaries, with each dictionary representing several statistics about the respective core. So I created this html "for" loop to display my cpus:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="table" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CPU utilization</th>
            <th>User time</th>
            <th>System time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {%for each in cores%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{each["cpuPerc"]}}</td>
                <td>{{each["cpuUserTime"]}}</td>
                <td>{{each["cpuSysTime"]}}</td>
            </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Now, the trouble is that I simple cannot figure out how to do the update process in this case. Am I supposed to create the table from scratch using jQuery?

Thanks for you input!

Answer (score 0):

What you can possibly do is add a simple number variable say i = 1 in your controller (sorry don't know flask) and when you loop over in the html add a class to each of those td's like:

```
    {%for each in cores%}
        <tr class="cpuCore">
            <td class="cpuPerc{{variablehere}}">{{each["cpuPerc"]}}</td>
            <td class="cpuUserTime{{variablehere}}">{{each["cpuUserTime"]}}</td>
            <td class="cpuSysTime{{variablehere}}">{{each["cpuSysTime"]}}</td>
        </tr>
        { increase the variable here so next time it will be say 2 instead of 1}
    {%endfor%}
```

Then you can have jquery look for those classes and update them based on their unique class names. Using the class name you gave to the tr's to get a count to loop over.

Changing your js to :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#memSizeGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memSizeGbUpdate");
        $("#memUsedGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memUsedGbUpdate");
        $("#memFreeGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memFreeGbUpdate");
        $("#memAvailGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memAvailGbUpdate");
        $("#memPercUsedUpdate").load("./memory.html #memPercUsedUpdate");
        $("#memPercFreeUpdate").load("./memory.html #memPercFreeUpdate");
    },1000);

    //This cpuCount is used for just checking the # of cpus in the html
    var cpuCount = $(".cpuCore").length
    // I am adding 1 to the count so that the jquery can still use the correct i number set in flask to check
    cpuCount += 1
    setInterval(function() {
        // we start at i = 1 so the jquery gets the right element with the selector
        for( i = 1; i < cpuCount; i++ ) {
            if($(".cpuPerc" + i)) {
                $("cpuPerc" + i).load(//add your path here)
                // add the other two 
            }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Just a possible answer, let me know if this helps get you on the right track.

**EDIT:**

Ok since I am not sure if you can update the variable in the for loop with flask either we will do it with jquery instead :)
Essentially all that is being done is adding that unique number that we were going to do in flask before with jquery instead.

html:

```
{%for each in cores%}
    <tr class="cpuCore">
        <td>{{each["cpuPerc"]}}</td>
        <td>{{each["cpuUserTime"]}}</td>
        <td>{{each["cpuSysTime"]}}</td>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Then you can have jquery add unique class/id names to the td's of each of the cpu tr cores:

Changing js to :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#memSizeGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memSizeGbUpdate");
        $("#memUsedGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memUsedGbUpdate");
        $("#memFreeGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memFreeGbUpdate");
        $("#memAvailGbUpdate").load("./memory.html #memAvailGbUpdate");
        $("#memPercUsedUpdate").load("./memory.html #memPercUsedUpdate");
        $("#memPercFreeUpdate").load("./memory.html #memPercFreeUpdate");
    },1000);


    var cpuCore = $(".cpuCore")
    var j = 1;
    // just looping over each of the cores (tr's) and adding a unique number to them so jquery can select them later for an ajax load
    cpuCore.each(function(idx, itm) { 
        itm.first().addClass("cpuPerc" + j);
        itm.first().next().addClass("cpuUserTime" + j);
        itm.first().next().next().addClass("cpuSysTime" + j);
    })

    // now like before we have jquery loop over them and load for them individually since they have unique classes. You can also add unique path's which I assume you have for them in your python dict
    var cpuCount = cpuCore.length;
    cpuCount += 1
    setInterval(function() {
        for( i = 1; i < cpuCount; i++ ) {
            if($(".cpuPerc" + i)) {
                $("cpuPerc" + i).load(//add your path here)
                // add the other two 
            }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I think it gets me closer to where I need to be. Yet, I have some trouble implementing your solution. The main issue is that flask as a python app can set variables for the html file (the "i" in this case), but I cannot increase the variable in the html loop, unless there is a way to do so WITHIN html - is that possible at all?

Comment: Alright I added an edit. Just did the variable part in jquery instead of flask. If you know how many cores to start you don't even have to do the loop to find them and then load just call them directly. If not this should help down the path of doing it dynamically. 

"within html" really only has one option, javascript. The for loop you currently have is really flask within the html not html itself. If we don't do it there the only other way is js.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot! TBH, I would be more comfortable doing this in Flask, but I cant seem to figure out how. I thought about the fixed core number solution, but I really would like to be able to run this on computers with different configurations. Anyway, thanks again!